# ADOQuery closes after constructor

Tags: delphi, ado, delphi-7

I am using `TADOQuery` in Delphi 7.
In the constructor, I call `ADOQuery.open`.

Why is the `ADOQuery` closed when another function is called from outside the form?

```
constructor TClass1.Create(AOwner: TComponent;
  MyParam: TProgramParam);
begin
  inherited;
  ADOQuery.Open;
  ADOQuery.Locate('fieldName',Param,[]);  
end;
```

Comment: You'd have to provide some info. Like, when what function is called?, outside what form? where does 'Class1' get the 'ADOQuery' since it doesn't create it?, etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My advise to find who is closing the DataSet:

Create a new event handler for the BeforeClose event of the AdoQuery, put anything that is compiled and executed just to put a Breakpoint there.  For example:

```
procedure TfrmCreDocCredito.cdsSucursalesBeforeClose(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  ShowMessage('Closing!!');
end;
```

Run your program, perform any user action needed to create your Class instance and when the program stops on the breakpoint, you have the chance to inspect the call stack.  It will reveal who, and if you think a bit about it, you will find why the dataset is closing.  If your breakpoint doesn't fire, I bet the dataset never really opens.

Best regards.

Comment: This is a genius idea, And I hold myself to ask, how didn't think of that myself :) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor TClass1.Create(AOwner: TComponent;
  MyParam: TProgramParam);
begin
  inherited;
  ADOQuery.Open;
  ADOQuery.Locate('fieldName',Param);  
end;

//

constructor TClass1.Create(AOwner: TComponent;
  MyParam: TProgramParam);
begin
  inherited;
  ADOQuery.Open;
  ADOQuery.Locate('fieldName',Param,[]);  
end;
```

Comment: I don't see the point in your *answer*. If you are trying to suggest that the third argument is missing in `Locate`, post a *comment* instead.